# jQuery add CSS class

Tags: jquery, css

I want to remove a css class before adding a new class to an element. If I know which exact class the element has already, I can remove that by

```
$('#test').removeClass('current_class').addClass('new_class');
```

But the problem is that `#test` does not have always same class. So I would like to remove any css class attached attached to `#test` before adding before adding a new one. How should I do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: It always helps to read the docs - [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#test').removeClass();
```

Will remove any class that the item has you can simply add your new class after that like you are doing now

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#test').attr('class', '').addClass('new_class');
```

or

```
$('#test').removeClass().addClass('new_class');
```

Answer (score 1):

How many different classes do you have?!

You could make a distinct check for each class

```
var not_allowed = ["class_1", "class_2", "class_3"];

for(i = 0; i < not_allowed.length; i++){
    if($("#test").hasClass(not_allowed[i])) $("#test").removeClass(not_allowed[i])
}

$("#test").addClass("new_class");
```

Or you could remove all classes at once with [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) without any parameters and then add the new class

```
$("#test").removeClass().addClass("new_class");
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly remove all the classes using jQuery's `removeClass()` function and  then add the classes according to your need.

Code is

```
$('your class').removeClass();
```